# Return Empty content on a url request in WKWebview

Tags: ios, swift, wkwebview

I want to return an empty content for the portion of the page that request a specific url.

I did the same in Android like this. This will return empty content when a specific url is requested. I want to do the same in iOS WKWebView.
I am trying to write in Swift 4.

```
     mWebView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {

        private Map<String, Boolean> loadedUrls = new HashMap<>();

        @TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.HONEYCOMB)
        @Override
        public WebResourceResponse shouldInterceptRequest(WebView view, String url) {
            return Utils.createEmptyResource();
        }

        @Override
        public void onPageStarted(WebView view, String url, Bitmap favicon) {
        }

        @Override
        public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {
        }
    });

    @TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.HONEYCOMB)
    public static WebResourceResponse createEmptyResource() {
        return new WebResourceResponse("text/plain", "utf-8", new ByteArrayInputStream("".getBytes()));
    }
```

This is the WKWebkit delegate function that I am using for this kind of functionality. But this function doesn't return a webresource, so  I will not be able to return an empty html here.

Below is the sample code.

```
func webView(_ webView: WKWebView, decidePolicyFor navigationAction: WKNavigationAction, decisionHandler: @escaping (WKNavigationActionPolicy) -> Void) {
        if let host = navigationAction.request.url?.host {
            decisionHandler(.allow)
            return
        }
        decisionHandler(.cancel)
    }
```

Any help is appreciated.

Thanks.